# how to convert a binary exponent to decimal?

Tags: math, ieee-754, floating-point-precision, floating-point-conversion

I am stuck with converting the smallest denormalized double precision number which is 2^-1074 to one in the form of power of 10. Any help regarding how can I do this will be appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `2^10 approx 10^3` to get `2^1070` approx. `10^(3*107)=10^321`. Combine with `2^4=16`...

---

To get the correct result, compute

```
log10(2^1074)=1074*log10(2)=323.306215343116
```

and take the integer part.